# как изменить цвет нажатого layouta

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout, color

```
val states = arrayOf(
    intArrayOf(android.R.attr.state_enabled),
    intArrayOf(android.R.attr.state_pressed)
)

val colors = intArrayOf(
    Color.BLACK,
    Color.RED,
)

val myList = ColorStateList(states, colors)
layout.backgroundTintList = MyList
```

пытался так но не получилось

Comment: Используйте метод setBackgroundColor

Comment: нет мне нужно изменить цвет зажатия а не самого лайоута

Comment: Ну повесьте слушатель onTouchListener и там используйте этот метод.

Comment: А как мне изменять обратно цвет если не нажат layout